# How is a star topology a regular graph?

Tags: graphs

A regular graph is one in which each vertex has the same number of neighbors, but in a star topology the central vertex is connected to more than one vertex. So, why is it referred to as a regular graph?

Comment: Star topology is not a regular graph.

Comment: In this research paper "Quantitative Comparison of Graph-Based Models for Internet Topology", they have considered it to be a regular graph

Comment: Of the four examples in Fig 3 of "Quantitative...", only the ring is a regular graph. This leads me the believe that they don't mean regular in the way you think, but instead simply mean a graph with nice/predictable structure.

Comment: *Then that paper is also wrong* unless authors mean something else by regular. [Regular is one of the most overloaded words in math](http://mathoverflow.net/questions/7389/what-are-the-most-overloaded-words-in-mathematics-closed).

Answer (score 3):

summarizing the comments: 
by the [standard definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_graph), a [star](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_graph) is not a regular graph.

They might defined "regular" in a different way than common to apply to star topology.  Specifically, in the paper the OP point out "regular" is never defined (and sparsely used).